Types not matching while using generics
I wanted to make a Discord bot using DiscordJS and TypeScript.
To make it faster to create components that can be added to Discord messages I made a componentprototype abstract class as follows (Note that Generators is just my own Subclasses of The Builders like ButtonBuilder etc.)
import { Awaitable, ButtonInteraction, StringSelectMenuInteraction, BaseInteraction} from "discord.js"
import { Logger, MyClient, ComponentGenerators } from "./index.js"
import { ButtonGenerator, StringSelectGenerator } from "../utils/index.js";

export interface CallbackProps<Interaction extends BaseInteraction | null> {
    interaction: Interaction,
    client: MyClient,
    log: Logger,
}

export type Callback<ReturnType, Interaction extends BaseInteraction | null, Args extends unknown[] = unknown[]> = (
    props: CallbackProps<Interaction>,
    ...args: Args
) => ReturnType;

export type VisibilityCallback = Callback<boolean, BaseInteraction | null>

type InteractionGeneratorMap<ComponentGenerator extends ComponentGenerators> = 
    ComponentGenerator extends ButtonGenerator ? ButtonInteraction : 
    ComponentGenerator extends StringSelectGenerator ?  StringSelectMenuInteraction :
    never;

export interface ComponentProtoData<Generator extends ComponentGenerators> {
    id: string,
    generator: Generator,
    visibilityCallback?: VisibilityCallback,
    callback?: Callback<Awaitable<unknown>, InteractionGeneratorMap<Generator>>
} 

export abstract class ComponentPrototype<Generator extends ComponentGenerators> implements ComponentProtoData<Generator>{

    public readonly id: string;

    public readonly generator: Generator;

    public readonly visibilityCallback: VisibilityCallback

    public readonly callback?: Callback<Awaitable<unknown>, InteractionGeneratorMap<Generator>>

    constructor(data: ComponentProtoData<Generator>) {
        this.id = data.id
        // ! set custom_id to id
        this.generator = data.generator
        this.generator.setCustomId(data.id)
        this.visibilityCallback = data.visibilityCallback ?? (() => true )
        this.callback = data.callback
    }
}

Then I made this Button:
export class Button extends ComponentPrototype<ButtonGenerator> {
    constructor(data: ComponentProtoData<ButtonGenerator>) {
        super(data)
    }
}

Now I wanted to make a Type that can have an Array of all of these possible Components using:
const components: ComponentPrototype<ComponentGenerators>[] = [new Button({id: "test", generator: ButtonGenerator.Back()})]

Error:
Type 'Button' is not assignable to type 'ComponentPrototype<ComponentGenerators>'.
  Types of property 'callback' are incompatible.
    Type 'Callback<unknown, ButtonInteraction<CacheType>, unknown[]> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Callback<unknown, ButtonInteraction<CacheType> | StringSelectMenuInteraction<CacheType>, unknown[]> | undefined'.
      Type 'Callback<unknown, ButtonInteraction<CacheType>, unknown[]>' is not assignable to type 'Callback<unknown, ButtonInteraction<CacheType> | StringSelectMenuInteraction<CacheType>, unknown[]>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Type 'CallbackProps<ButtonInteraction<CacheType> | StringSelectMenuInteraction<CacheType>>' is not assignable to type 'CallbackProps<ButtonInteraction<CacheType>>'.
            Type 'ButtonInteraction<CacheType> | StringSelectMenuInteraction<CacheType>' is not assignable to type 'ButtonInteraction<CacheType>'.
              Type 'StringSelectMenuInteraction<CacheType>' is not assignable to type 'ButtonInteraction<CacheType>'.ts(2322)


Button extends ComponentPrototype<ButtonGenerator> can never be the same as ComponentPrototype<ComponentGenerators>. I guess your issue lies here.
